# When try to call function from Controller it doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jointjs

I'm trying to call a function in my jointController from other javascript file.

```
var app1 = angular.module('jointApp',[]);
var createStateBox = function(label,color){

var state = new uml.State({
    position: {x: 0, y: 0},
    size: {width: 200, height: 100},
    name: "<<"+label+">>",
    events: [label+" box"],
    attrs:{rect:{fill:color},path:{"stroke-width":0}}

});
app1.controller('jointController', function($scope) {
    $scope.setDecision(state);
    alert("This is reached");
});
    paper.model.addCell(state);
}
```

Here is the code in jointMod.js which contains jointController

```
var app = angular.module('jointApp', []);

function JointController($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.list = [];

    $scope.newMsg = 'hello';
    $scope.newDecision;

    $scope.setMsg = function(msg) {
        $scope.newMsg = msg;
    }

    $scope.sendPost = function() {
        var data = $.param({
        json: JSON.stringify({
            msg: $scope.newMsg
            })
         });

    $scope.setDecision = function(decision){
        $scope.newDecision = decision;
        alert("one two one two")
        console.log(decision);
    }

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://213.65.171.121:3000/decision',
        data: $scope.newMsg,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            str.push(encodeURIComponent("action") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj));
            return str.join("&");
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.list.push(status);
        }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.list.push(status);
        });
    };
};
```

I have the alert and console log in there to make sure if they can be reach but they do not responed.

Comment: Do you want to use first $scope to second controller ?

Comment: O ok now i understand what i have done wrong but how do i use the $scope from second controller in first codes?(i just want to use the seconde controller)

Comment: I think i  need to update my question: i understand that i didn't create the controller in the right way and in the first part code i made a mistake to create a different module and controller. But the question i want to ask is. Is it possible to call functions of a controller which is inside a javascript file from other javascript file(not html) and if possible, how do you do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided will not function as you may think. Atleast not if you use both together.

Both codes introduce a new module `jointApp` and actually only the first one defines a controller. The `$scope` of that controller is NOT the same of the function in your second code.

If you want to call a method from outside of a controller take a look at events in angular. That would be the best way to archive this. You could also use a dummy object and two-way-bind it (`scope: { dummy: '=' }`) and then call the method you create on that object in your directive from other code-parts.

Take a look at this plnkr demonstrating both approaches.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YdcB10UpXGqKAxYzXISL?p=preview

Comment: thank you, i will take a look in that, i wanted the first code part to call the $scope.setDecision function in the second code part, is that possible?

Comment: I have added a plnkr to demonstrate both approaches.

Comment: Your two code parts are currently not combinable. Read the angular doc regarding modules and how controllers are defined.

Comment: Take a look at my plnkr example. It should give you enough clues where to start.

Comment: Yes i understand, but the example you give me only shows how to call the  controller in a html file, now what i want is to call it in a javascript(jointJS) file. That is also possible or?

Comment: If you look careful you will find that the buttons merely call javascript code.